# How to check if a category has a parent and child categories?

Tags: php, categories

Im trying to check if 'categoryone' has a parent. Right know I can check and see that there is a category called categoryone, but I want to check categoryone for parent and child categories. I have tried to code something like the code bellow.
Finaly my goal is to use wp_set_post_categorie(); after the category check.

```
 foreach ( $network_posts as $network_post ) {

  // Add the new post
  $insert_id = wp_insert_post( $network_post->post );

  // Add metadata (useful for lookups later)
  update_post_meta( $insert_id, '_network_content', 1 );
  update_post_meta( $insert_id, '_network_site_orig_id', array(
'site_id' => $bid,
'post_id' => $network_post->id,
 ) );



 $tid = term_exists('categoryone', 'category', 0);

 $term_ids = [];

 if ( $tid !== 0 && $tid !== null )
 {
  $term_ids[] = $tid['term_id'];

 }
 else
 {
  $insert_term_id = wp_insert_term( 'categoryone', 'category' );
  if ( ! is_wp_error )
  $term_ids[] = $insert_term_id;
  }
  wp_set_post_categories( $insert_id, $term_ids );
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all consider that if the category exists, `term_exists` function return an array, not a term id. See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists#Return_Values).

So:

```
$term_ids = array();

$term = term_exists('categoryone', 'category', 0);

if ( is_array($term) && isset($term['term_id']) ) { // term exists as parent cat
  $term_ids[] = $term['term_id'];
  // get all the children of the categories
  $children = get_categories( array( 'parent'=> $term['term_id'], 'hide_empty'=>false) );
  if ( ! empty($children) ) {
     // category exist as parent and also have children
     // do you want to add also the children? If so:
     $children_ids = wp_list_pluck($children, 'term_id');
     $term_ids = array_merge($term_ids, $children_ids);
  } else {
     // category exist as parent but has no children   
  }
} else { // term does not exists as parent cat
  $insert_term_id = wp_insert_term( 'categoryone', 'category' );
  $term_ids[] = $insert_term_id;
}
```

And then, if `$insert_id` is the ID of a post you can use:

```
wp_set_post_categories( $insert_id, $term_ids );
```

For more info see codex for

- [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)
- [wp_list_pluck](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)

Comment: Hi, I have changed my code a little bit, and know I wonder how to use $insert_id with wp_set_post_categories();.